# SORT and ORDER BY in Asian AND European Languages

Tags: sorting, sql-order-by, multilingual

I'm in an environment using both Asian (mostly Chinese, Korean and Japanese) AND European (English, French, German, and so on) Languages, and I tried sorting a table with both languages.

I am aware that LC_COLLATE="C" will help me sort in Korean, but doing so does not correctly sort French, and it seemed like many other people are struggling with this issue. I would like to know if anyone figured out a solution for this problem.

I'm new to PostgreSQL so I apologize I can't ask my question with more detail.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: +1 apart from collations, no idea... but I'm be interested in answers since I am frequently working in highly multilingual environments!